# How to track a large project with Git and migrate into Github

Tags: git, github

The company in which I work doesn't have use git tracking. It used Dropbox to synchronise files and folders. It wants to migrate a big project into Github (+600 MB). I don't know if it's possible or how long should we wait for the migration. I know that we should put some directories and files in .gitignore but which ones to put?
How can i determine files and directories to put in .gitignore?

My connection:
[image: My connection here]

Comment: Is it a project which has never had `git tracking`?

Comment: Yes that's it, and I don't know if It's possible to track now +600 MB of data (some data will be no tracked of course)

Comment: Is it code? What are the files?

Comment: There are images, code with CodeIgniter framework, JS, CSS and maybe others files according to permissions of acces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually ignore all kinds of auto-generated files, like those generated during a softwares build process (e.g. VisualStudios `/bin` and `/obj` folders), and also files containing local settings (i.e. settings that are specific to the developers machine). The repository should contain all files that are necessary to build the project, so that a new contributor can just clone the repository, build and start the software.

The amount of files to ignore does not correlate in any way with project size. There are plenty of exemplary `.gitignore` files for different programming languages and environments.

> I don't know if it's possible or how long should we wait for the migration.

Why should it not be possible? And why wait?

Comment: Thank's for your reply, I should init git in my project so I use git itnit, after I have to commit and push in plateform like Github or GitLab. So push will take time?

Comment: Yes, it will take time, depending on your connection. With an average european internet connection, I don't think it will take longer than 30 minutes.

Comment: I put update the post at the top. Do you think ithe connetion is pretty good

Comment: It's 0.5 Megabit per second upstream, that's 0.0625 Megabyte per second, thats 600MB : 0.0625 MB/s = 9600s = 160 min. So, using the full bandwith, the push may take as long as three hours. I do not see a problem here. Why don't you just try it?

Comment: before initialising i have to determine all files to ignore. If there are no problem i will try it. Thank you for details and for your help

Comment: If I answered your question, please accept it as answer. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).